# How can I escape double quotes in XML attributes values?

Tags: xml

From the following trials

```
<tag attr="\"">
<tag attr="<![CDATA["]]>">
<tag attr='"'>
```

Only the last one works for an XML parser that I'm using here.
Is there an alternative?

Comment: **`&quot;`** is the answer;  [**here's the explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534887/290085).

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)*

Answer (score 297, accepted):

You can use `&quot;`

Answer (score 61):

From the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax):

> To allow attribute values to contain
>   both single and double quotes, the
>   apostrophe or single-quote character
>   (') may be represented as "&apos;",
>   and the double-quote character (") as
>   "&quot;".

Answer (score 40):

A double quote character (`"`) *can* be escaped as `&quot;`, but here's the rest of the story...

### Double quote character *must* be escaped in this context:

- In XML attributes delimited by double quotes:

  ```
  <EscapeNeeded name="Pete &quot;Maverick&quot; Mitchell"/>
  ```

### Double quote character *need not* be escaped in most contexts:

- In XML textual content:

  ```
  <NoEscapeNeeded>He said, "Don't quote me."</NoEscapeNeeded>
  ```
- In XML attributes delimited by single quotes (`'`):

  ```
  <NoEscapeNeeded name='Pete "Maverick" Mitchell'/>
  ```

  Similarly, (`'`) require no escaping if (`"`) are used for the attribute value delimiters:

  ```
  <NoEscapeNeeded name="Pete 'Maverick' Mitchell"/>
  ```

### See also

- [**Simplified XML Escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)

Answer (score 8):

The [String conversion](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/) page on the [Coder's Toolbox](http://coderstoolbox.net/) site is handy for encoding more than a small amount of HTML or XML code for inclusion as a value in an XML element.