# XML has single and double quotes, need to escape both in one

Tags: xml, escaping

I have a XML line that looks like this:

```
<test>
   <title name='AND error-based (BIGINT)'/>
   <payload start='AND (SELECT 2*(IF((SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT('"[rand_string]"', ("[query]"), '"[rand_string]"','x'))s), "[big_int_1]", "[big_int_2]"'/>
</test>
```

This isn't working because the string contains both `'` and `"`. How can I escape  the quote in the middle of the string to make this valid XML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape double quotes in XML attributes values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961505/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-xml-attributes-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape quotation mark as `&quot;` or `&#34;`, and you can escape apostrophe as `&#39;`.

Comment: Yes it will work. I tend to avoid it because it's predefined in XML but not in HTML, but I can never remember which...

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, idk anything about xml and decided to learn lol