# Target directory with space in PuTTY pscp via NAnt

Tags: putty, nant, pscp

This target is **OK** (`D:\Temp\sgr.tar.gz`):

```xml
  <target name="myTarget" description="Download application delivery file">
    <exec program="pscp.exe">
        <arg line="-batch -v -l ${ftp.user} -pw ${ftp.password} ${ftp.host}:${remote.dir}/${remote.file} D:\Temp\sgr.tar.gz"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

This target (with a space in target directory (`D:\tmp 2\sgr.tar.gz`)) is **KO**:

```xml
  <target name="myTarget" description="Download application delivery file">
    <exec program="pscp.exe">
        <arg line="-batch -v -l ${ftp.user} -pw ${ftp.password} ${ftp.host}:${remote.dir}/${remote.file} D:\Temp\tmp 2.tar.gz"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

I have this error:

> [exec] More than one remote source not supported

I try with  but is KO also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the path to double-quotes (`&quot`):

```xml
    <arg line="-batch -v -l ${ftp.user} -pw ${ftp.password} ${ftp.host}:${remote.dir}/${remote.file} &quot;D:\Temp\tmp 2.tar.gz&quot;"/>
```

See [How to escape double quotes in XML attributes values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3961505/850848)